# Fast calculation of eigenvector centrality takes too long in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, igraph, eigenvector

I am using networkx to calculate eigenvector centrality. The problem is that it takes way too long (already running for about 6 hours). 
Is there a faster way to get the results?

There are around 200,000 nodes in the graph and 60,000,000 edges.

Comment: yes. but you will need to use an external module outside networkx. In any case, the dimensionality of the eigenvector is going to be 200000 so it's fine.

Comment: @serafeim what do you mean by external module?

Comment: I mean without using networkx function to calculate the leading eigenvector. Using ARPACK you could find the leading eigenvector of the adjacency in a faster way. Can you give more information? What does the 200000 nodes represent? Also, if you post some data I can post an answer

Comment: see my answer that answers your question and provides dome additional ideas

Comment: Networkx has a built-in method for doing it faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the source code, `networkx.algorithms.centrality.eigenvector` uses the power method to find the leading eigenvector.

**If you stick to `networkx` use this as Joel noticed:**

[eigenvector_centrality_numpy](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.eigenvector_centrality_numpy.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.eigenvector_centrality_numpy)

```
centrality = nx.eigenvector_centrality_numpy(G)
```

**Alternatively:**

You can use `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` that uses the ARPACK and request only 1 eigenvector to be returned.

Toy example:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse

X = np.array() # dimensions 200000 by 200000 as the adjacency
# Note: k=1 and you request the Largest real.
vals, vecs = sparse.linalg.eigs(X, k=1, which='LR')
```

In any case, 2000000 by 200000 is big and depending on the sparsity and the nature of the matrix, the algorithm may take long. You will also need a lot of CPU and RAM.

**Additional tip for `networkx.algorithms.centrality.eigenvector`:**

If you stick with networkx try to relax the tolerance:

`eigenvector_centrality(G, max_iter=100, tol=1e-06, nstart=None, weight=None)`

Try setting `tol=1e-04` or even `tol=1e-03`

Comment: networkx already has this built-in as `eigenvector_centrality_numpy.`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [eigenvector_centrality_numpy](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.eigenvector_centrality_numpy.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.eigenvector_centrality_numpy). From the documentation:

> This algorithm uses the SciPy sparse eigenvalue solver (ARPACK) to find the largest eigenvalue/eigenvector pair.

So this will do serafeim's calculation, with a tiny bit of additional processing.